# Use Setuptools with C Extension as part of package

Tags: python, c, setuptools, packaging, python-extensions

I wrote a C Extension to access an error message for a camera from a proprietary library. The structure is

```
setup.py
dicamsdk\
|---__init__.py
|---control.py
|---pcoError.c
```

with `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from dicamsdk.control import __version__

pcoErrorModule = Extension("dicamsdk.pcoError",
                           sources=["dicamsdk/pcoError.c"],
                           include_dirs=['C:\Program Files (x86)'
                                         '\Digital Camera Toolbox'
                                         '\Sensicam SDK\include'],
                           define_macros=[("PCO_ERRT_H_CREATE_OBJECT", None)],
                           )
setup(
    name="pydicamsdk",
    platforms=["win-amd64", 'win32'],
    license="GNU GPLv3",
    ext_modules=[pcoErrorModule],
    packages=find_packages(),
    version=__version__
)
```

and the `control.py` intends to import the compiled C Extension with

```
from . import pcoError
```

When I try to build (or install) the package I always receive the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'pcoError'`.

The only way it seems to work is to comment out the import in `control.py` and build the C Extension with `setup.py build_ext --inplace`. Just with the compiled present I can build/install my library.

Is there a solution to be implemented in my `setup.py` to compile my extension in first place to enable a simple installation?

Comment: S.O. is great. What are the odds someone else had the exact same issue as you, right?

Answer (score 3):

A more proper solution based on your own answer:

Your version is presumably for the entire project, not just the control module. It is standard to define `__version__` in `__init__.py`. In that case, your import in `setup.py` would look like `from dicamsdk import __version__`. This will cause no conflicts, unless you do something foolish like import all your modules automatically from the package root.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the import at the beginning of `setup.py`. The import in line 2 (`from dicamsdk.control import __version__`) forced the code check of the module.

When removed, the install or build of the packages runs correctly.